# Matlab unable to open the .dat file as data file when calling a software using 'system'

Tags: matlab

To generate an ouput file (.rwo format) containing the desired result, we have to run the executable of the report program which uses a parameter file (.rwd format). The output file is ReportBHP1.rwo, this file will contain the variable exported.

Now to implement this in Matlab, below is a small script giving a gist of what I am trying to achieve. It call CMG (software) for each realization and extracts the data.

```
for nr=1:NREAL

      dlmwrite(‘PERM.INC’,PERM(:,nr),’delimiter’,’\n’); % Writes the permeability file for each realization

      system('mx200810.exe -f ReservoirModel_CMGBulider.dat')  % Calls CMG
      system('report.exe /f ReportBHP1.rwd /o ReportBHP1.rwo') % Calls Parameter file and generates output file

      [TIME(:,j),BHP1(:,j)]=textread('ReportBHP1.rwo','%f\t%f','headerlines',5); % reading the time and BHP from output file generated for well 1

end
```

All of my software's required `.exe` and `.dll` files are in the same folder where I have my `ReservoirModel_CMGBulider.dat` file. So I am running the `.m` file through the same folder where I have all these files.

I am able to generate the output (.rwo) file. However there is an error in the simulation report of the software which is displayed in Matlab's command window as follow:

```
"...STOP: Unable to open the following file as data file:
              'ReservoirModel_CMGBuilder.dat'
              Check path name for spaces, special character or a total length greater than 256 characters

              Cannot find data file named 'ReservoirModel_CMGBuilder.dat'

Date and Time of End of Run: .....

ans = 0"
```

I think its reading the .dat file only one time and then overwriting the first realization result in rest of the realizations. As a consequence of this the result of all the realizations is coming out to be same as the first realization. I need help in correcting this error.

Comment: No idea how to solve the problem, but please let me know if you find some good oil pockets :-)

Comment: I didn't understand your phrase 'oil pockets'.

Comment: BHP, permeability, well, reservoir...

Comment: Can you run these commands manually multiple times in this directory from a command shell? (Also, I dont see the point of the loop, does PERM.INC get picked by your software automatically?)

Comment: What I have shown here is basically just part of the code. There different .INC files, and I am showing only 1 here. PERM.INC file basically stores the permeability values which are extracted by the software's 'ReservoirModel_CMGBuilder.dat' file automatically (by adding one command line in the .dat file).

Comment: @ Mau: It worked by adding the full path :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if my previous answer was OK, could you accept it? Thanks!

Second, have you tried using full path names for all the files as before?

Comment: Hey Jacob. Your previous answer was ofcourse useful. However it couldn't solve the problem. If accepting answer is based on being OK (also) apart from being the solution, then I can surely do that :) . You can see my EDIT 2 for the command which solved the output file issue.

Comment: Full path names is not helping. I could generate the output file without that by keeping all the files in one folder. See my EDIT 2 in the link where I have accepted your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I tried again and adding the full path for .dat file worked. Sometimes it was strange because even adding the full path was not helping. Now its working. :-)